# Which levels contain achievement pickups?

Tags: achievements, thomas-was-alone

Some levels in Thomas Was Alone have achievement pickups - small black hollow rectangles which give you an achievement when picked up. Unfortunately the description on Steam of these achievements don't list the levels which they appear in, making it difficult to go back to find them. Which levels have these pickups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming they're the same as the PS3/Vita version, there are two achievement pickups in each of the following levels, which you need to find both of:

- Spawn (0.3, 0.5)
- Array (1.8, 1.9)
- Origin (2.4, 2.9)
- Associations (3.4, 3.8)
- Purge (4.4, 4.8)
- Invert (5.1, 5.4)
- Iterate (6.2, 6.7)
- Design (7.1, 7.10)
- Generation (8.5, 8.10)
- Y+1, X+1 (9.2, 9.10)